# Making a histogram via matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem. I'm doing a task for my lessons and I'm doing my best, but the teacher does not seem to care and I need to look for the problem myself facing his demands.

I had to make a program, it does not important of what, I don't bother explaining it. I just need to make a histogram to show results, the problem is I can't use .hist() because we need to make OUR histogram via .bar() using matplotlib library.

Here is the code:

```
import random
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


list = []
N = 1000
for i in range(N):
    x_1 = random.random()
    x_2 = random.random()
    xx = ((-2 * math.log(x_1)) ** (1 / 2)) * math.sin(2 * math.pi * x_2)
    xy = ((-2 * math.log(x_1)) ** (1 / 2)) * math.cos(2 * math.pi * x_2)

    list.append(xx)
    list.append(xy)

plt.hist(list, alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

I need to change the plt.hist() to plt.bar(), doing so I end up with this:

```
plt.bar(list, y_pos, align='center', alpha=0.5)
```

And the bars overlay, the histogram is unclear. The teacher's assistand told me to sum up the bars like this: when the value if between let's say 1-1.99 you add those values to bar 1, when 2-2.99 to bar 2 etc.

Don't know how to do this, please help.

Comment: Why can't you use hist? Why is it not important for us to know about the problem you're trying to solve? Is this homework, and thus why you're trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Where are you getting y_pos from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, using numpy allows [vectorization](https://realpython.com/numpy-array-programming/) and makes everything much faster. Also, please don't use `list` as a variable name because it overwrites the standard function with that name.

To calculate a histogram "by hand" isn't that difficult.
First you need to decide about some bins, usually they are regularly spaced over the complete domain of the data. Default, `plt.hist` uses 10 bins, equally divided over the range from the minimum to the maximum of the data

Then, you create an array to count the number of `x` that fall inside each of the 10 bins. To know in which of the bins (numbered 0 to 9) a particular `x` falls, subtract the minimum x and divide by the range. This gives a number between 0 and 1. Multiplying by the number of bins gives a float number between 0 and 10. Converting the number to an integer gives the index of the bin which should be incremented by one. A multiplication by a number slightly lower than 1 prevents that the maximum x would be put into bin index 10 which doesn't exist.

The code below first creates a bar plot in yellow and then draws a standard histogram in transparent red on top of it. As both coincide perfectly, together they show an orange histogram.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 1000
x_1 = np.random.random(N)
x_2 = np.random.random(N)
xx = ((-2 * np.log(x_1)) ** (1 / 2)) * np.sin(2 * np.pi * x_2)
xy = ((-2 * np.log(x_1)) ** (1 / 2)) * np.cos(2 * np.pi * x_2)
lst = np.concatenate([xx, xy])
minx = min(lst)
maxx = max(lst)
bins = 10
bin_counts = np.zeros(bins)
bin_factor = bins * 0.999999 / (maxx - minx)
for x in lst:
    bin_counts[int((x - minx) * bin_factor)] += 1

plt.bar(np.linspace(minx, maxx, bins, endpoint=False), bin_counts, width=(maxx - minx) / bins,
        alpha=.5, ec='w', align='edge', color='yellow')
plt.hist(lst, alpha=0.5, bins=bins, ec='w', color='red')

plt.show()
```

To draw a standard gaussian normal over the histogram, it needs to be scaled by the number of samples and adjusted for the width of the bars:

```py
from scipy.stats import norm
x = np.linspace(minx, maxx, 200)
plt.plot(x, norm.pdf(x, 0, 1)*len(lst)/bin_factor, color='green', lw=2)
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: You might want to read more about the [Box-Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform).

To have bars that are only 0.1 wide, you could change the code as follows. You'd also need a larger N to avoid that the bars would have very irregular heights.

```py
minx = -2
maxx = 2
bins = 40
bin_counts = np.zeros(bins)
factor = bins * 0.999999 / (maxx - minx)
for x in lst:
    if minx <= x <= maxx:  # this test is needed when minx is larger than the real minimum (similar for maxx)
        bin_counts[int((x - minx) * factor)] += 1

# optionally show ticks every .1 steps
plt.xticks(np.arange(minx, maxx+0.001, 0.1), rotation=90)
```

The following plot uses `N = 10000`

[image: plot with steps of 0.1]

Answer (score 0):

Whoa, excellent. This looks awesome. I hope there won't be any problems with x axis with labels. Would there be a way to divide it by 10? So I can get for example -0.3, -0.2,-0.1,0,0.1,0.2,0.3 ?

I've also done that method with other task.

```
import math
from scipy import constants
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


kb = constants.Boltzmann

m = 5e-26

var = (kb*300/m)**(1/2)

v_list = []
v = 0
N = 1000
for i in range(N):
    x_1 = random.random()
    x_2 = random.random()
    n1 = ((-2 * math.log(x_1, math.e)) ** (1 / 2)) * math.cos(2 * math.pi * x_2) * var
    n2 = ((-2 * math.log(x_1, math.e)) ** (1 / 2)) * math.sin(2 * math.pi * x_2) * var

    y_1 = random.random()
    y_2 = random.random()
    n3 = ((-2 * math.log10(y_1)) ** (1 / 2)) * math.cos(2 * math.pi * y_2) * var
    v += math.sqrt(n1*n1+n2*n2+n3*n3)

    if math.sqrt(n1*n1+n2*n2+n3*n3) <= 900:
        v_list.append(math.sqrt(n1*n1+n2*n2+n3*n3))
    else:
        continue


minx = min(v_list)
maxx = max(v_list)
bins = 10
bin_counts = np.zeros(bins)
factor = bins * 0.999999 / (maxx - minx)

for x in v_list:
    bin_counts[int((x - minx) * factor)] += 1

plt.bar(np.linspace(minx, maxx, bins, endpoint=False), bin_counts, width=(maxx - minx) / bins,
        alpha=0.5, ec='w', align='edge', color='green')

plt.show()
```

I've got some problems with plt.savefig() but it worked later. Also could not transfer the math library to numpy, so I left it like this.

EDIT: I may be having a cool task with Mandelbrot set later, I was looking for answer all across the place but could not manage. It has some strange approach which I could not learn how to solve. All this to addidion of teachers not wanting to simply tell me the answer. I had high hopes for that Python lessos but what I'm left with is just simply disgust.